# OpenCSV - register custom converter

Tags: java, enums, javabeans, opencsv

So I'm using opencsv to convert a csv to beans.
This all works fine with primitive values, but I want to use enums and this is giving some issues.

I'm going through the code, and it seems I need to completely implement a new mappingstrategy to do this just to set a custom convertor. Is there a better way for this?

Current code for the conversion:

```
CsvToBean<MyType> csvBean = new CsvToBeanBuilder<MyType>(new FileReader(csvFile))
                 .withType(MyType.class)
                 .withIgnoreLeadingWhiteSpace(true)
                 .withFieldAsNull(CSVReaderNullFieldIndicator.EMPTY_QUOTES)
                 .build();
```

I found some questions from 2012 in regards to this, but the answers are no longer applicable for the current opencsv version (4.2).

Comment: You might be able to work around this with a custom setter that accepts a String but uses property field that has an enum as the type. Just do a `MyEnum.valueOf()`

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Ok it turns out there's a `@CsvCustomBindByName(column = 'foo', converter = Bar.class)`

Annotation that does exactly what I want. This class just needs to be of type `<T> extends AbstractBeanField<T>`

Comment: Were you able to pass dependencies to this custom converter class? E.g. I want to pass a dependency to converter class' constructor that will be used to transform the initial value. `public Bar (MyDependency instance){}`

Answer (score 1):

So what I have done in similar situations where I have a bunch of primitives but I want a complex object (an object with imbedded objects) is to have an intermediate object.  I call them DTO (Data Transfer Objects), though I am sure there is a more appropriate name for it,  that openCSV will populate and then the DTO can build the complex object I want from the primitives it contains.

Comment: I found an annotation driven way, might also be useful for you.